# Building a hash out of hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to write my code more compact. I have three hashes. The first hash (@hash) is a collection of sub-hashes (value_1, value_2)

```
@hash = {
  "Key" => ["value_1", "value_2"]
}

@value_1 = {
  "Foo" => ["bar_1", "bar_2"]
}

@value_2 = {
  "Foo2" => ["bar2_1", "bar2_2"]
}
```

Now, in my haml-view i'm trying to make something like this:

```
- i = 0

- @hash.each_value do |value|
  - @value_[i].each_pair do |k, v|
    = k
    = v[0]

- i = i +1
```

I don't want to write one hash after the other. It's a bit similar to making a symbol out of a string, where you can write somthing like "value_#{i}".to_sym. I hope, somebody can follow and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@hashes = [
           {
             "Foo" => ["bar_1", "bar_2"]
           }, 
           {
             "Foo2" => ["bar2_1", "bar2_2"]
           }
   ]
```

Then

```
@hashes.each do |v|
  v.each_pair do |k,v|
    = k
    = v[0]
```

And if you need the index use `each_with_index`.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
 - @hash.each_value do |value|
  - value.each do |v|
    - instance_variable_get(:"@#{v}").each_pair do |k, val|
      = k
      = val[0]
```

[API](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get)

Comment: My hashes are full to the brim. I'm trying to avoid to touch anything there. I thought there will be just a simnple trick in the view. A little kung-fu style :-)

Comment: Try this: - @hash.each_value do |value|
  - value.each do |v|
    - send(:"@#{v}").each_pair do |k, val|
      = k
      = val[0]

Comment: Yes, that's it. And i don't know what happens in line 3, but it seems to be the kung-fu i wanted. Thank you very much.